# Python (3.6.1) keypress detection and popups

Tags: python, popup, keypress, msvcrt

Im kinda new to python and i tried printing the key when pressed on windows and show the key in a popup message:

```
import msvcrt
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.

def Mbox(title, text, style):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit()== True:
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        print(key)  # just to show the result
        Mbox(key, key, 1)
```

And the problems are:

1) The output if i press a key is diffrent, for example :"**A**" is "**b'A'**"
why? and how can i change it to only "**A**"? (the output on the popup is even weirder like : 1X when i press 1 or 2*x when i press 2)

2) Is `While True:` makes the code run all the time, and by that keeps it detecting if a key has been pressed?

3) Is there any lib for python which detects a key-press for **windows** and **Linux** altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found some answers:

1) `msvcrt.getwch()`
Wide char variant of getch(), returning a Unicode value.

Read more at: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html

2) I Guess yes, if someone can confirm it ill be glad.

3) Not that i know, there are diff libs for each op system (again if im wrong please leave a note here).